# Can a .co.uk domain be converted to private anonymous registration?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, private-registration

I have a domain which I have registered in my own name and address. Is there anyway that I can make this private?

I am currently using GoDaddy. I have seen 123-reg offer a private registration when you register a new domain.

Comment: I use GoDaddy for all of my site registrations and they have an option for privacy that is amongst the best and rather smooth functioning since it is a company that GoDaddy owns. I have been happy with my private registrations and I recommend it for you. Of course there are other companies that may offer a similar service for less, but there is nothing like handling the whole shabang in one simple transaction year after year. Easy peasy!

Comment: @closetnoc GoDaddy won't let me make an existing registration anon.

Comment: They did for me. I used to be a registered ISP and webhost and I used GoDaddy since they launched. In the past few years, I have been cleaning house of old domains and needed to update the registration with an address that was not my office. September 2 years ago, I changed the address and made all registrations private. These were all domains that have been around for years. In fact, only a few original domains were still registered with Network Solutions and had to be transferred. But the rest had been registered with GoDaddy for years. All are private now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [GoDaddy help page about adding private registration](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/420/adding-private-registration-to-your-domain-names).   It states:

> Private Registration is available for many domain name extensions. However, some registries do not allow it. If the registry does not allow privacy, the Privacy tab is not available in the domain name's Upgrade section of the Domain Manager.

If the option is not in the upgrade section, then GoDaddy does not offer private registration for `.co.uk` domains.

[Here is an article](http://www.itpro.co.uk/data-protection/22477/home-addresses-to-be-published-online-by-uk-domain-firm-nominet) that says there was a recent policy change.   `.co.uk` registrations can no longer be private for businesses, only for individuals using the domains for non-commercial purposes.

Nominet is the company that owns the `.co.uk` TLD.   Their [website states](http://www.nominet.org.uk/uk-domain-names/about-domain-names/domain-lookup-whois/opt-out):

> ...if you are the registrant and a non-trading individual, you can log into your Nominet online account and select the opt-out [of whois] button on the Account Summary page.

So even if GoDaddy doesn't offer private registration, it appears that you can remove your details from whois through Nominet.